# How to get number of hosts in Hadoop Cluster, their IP and rack

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cluster-computing, hosts, system-administration

I'm working on a cluster but I don't know how many hosts it has exactly, which are their IPs and what rack they belong to. 
I've previously worked with clusters managed via Cloudera and got that information from the cloudera api (http://cloudera.github.io/cm_api/apidocs/v16/), in particular this (http://cm_server_host:7180/api/v16/hosts) gave me all the info I was looking for. But how can I do that if the cluster doesn't use Cloudera? It has spark as well, but since there is Hadoop and HDFS I think the information is more likely to be found there.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find those information via http api, that by default should be available under this url:

`http://<namenodehost>:50070`

and via YARN http api, that by default should be available under this url:

```
http://<resourcemanagerhost>:8088/cluster/nodes
```

Alternatively you can use ResourceManager REST API’s.

```
http://<resourcemanagerhost>:8088/ws/v1/cluster/nodes
```

More about the topic you can find for example here:

https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/collecting-hadoop-metrics/

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping! I got some of the needed information: how many nodes are in the cluster, their ip addresses, what I am missing though is the rack they belong to and the number of cores on the machines. Is there any way to get those info? I read through the article but couldn't find anything about that :/

Comment: Thanks, that's what I needed! Do you know if I can get a Json version? So when I automate it I don't have to parse through the html